# Navbar disappears when adding blur

Tags: html, css, sass

Whenever I bring up a menu that adds blur to the page wrapper, my fixed position navbar disappears and I have no idea as to why. Furthermore, it only happens when I scroll past the very top of the page. At the top, the navbar is blurred along with the rest of the page and gives the desired effect. Scrolling past that section, however, leads to the navbar disappearing from view instead of being blurred.

Html:

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header" class="alt">
            <div class="navbar-logo">
                <a href="index.html" class="a-label"><img class="label" src="images/Logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="logos">
                <a href="index.html" class="logo">Home</a>
                <a href="#products" class="logo">Products</a>
                <a href="#gallery" class="logo">Gallery</a>
                <a href="recipes.html" class="logo">Recipes</a>
                <a href="contact.html" class="logo">Contact Us</a>
            </div>  
            <nav>
                <a href="#menu" class="nav-menu"></a>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- Menu -->
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

    <!-- Other Page Content -->
</div>
```

Css for the navbar:

```css
#header {
    @include vendor('display', 'flex');
    background-color: _palette(bg-alt);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    cursor: default;
    font-weight: _font(weight-bold);
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow:auto;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    .logos {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .logo {
        border: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14pt;
        height: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        padding: 0 1em;
    }

    nav {
        @include vendor('display', 'flex');
        @include vendor('justify-content', 'flex-end');
        @include vendor('flex-grow', '1');
        height: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;

        a {
            border: 0;
            display: block;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            height: inherit;
            line-height: inherit;
            padding: 0 0.75em;
            position: relative;

            &:last-child {
                padding-right: 1.5em;
            }

            &[href="#menu"] {
                padding-right: 3.325em !important;

                &:before, &:after {
                    background-image: svg-url('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 32" preserveAspectRatio="none"><style>line { stroke-width: 2px; stroke: #{_palette(fg-bold)}; }</style><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="24" y2="11" /><line x1="0" y1="21" x2="24" y2="21" /><line x1="0" y1="16" x2="24" y2="16" /></svg>');
                    background-position: center;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: 24px 32px;
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    height: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 1.5em;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 24px;
                }

                &:after {
                    @include vendor('transition', 'opacity #{_duration(transition)} ease-in-out');
                    background-image: svg-url('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 32" preserveAspectRatio="none"><style>line { stroke-width: 2px; stroke: #{royalblue}; }</style><line x1="0" y1="11" x2="24" y2="11" /><line x1="0" y1="21" x2="24" y2="21" /><line x1="0" y1="16" x2="24" y2="16" /></svg>');
                    opacity: 0;
                    z-index: 1;
                }

                &:hover, &:active {
                    &:after {
                        opacity: 1;
                    }
                }

                &:last-child {
                    padding-right: 3.875em !important;

                    &:before, &:after {
                        right: 2em;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    body.is-preload & {
        &.alt {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    .nav-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    @include breakpoint('<=large') {
        .navbar-logo {
            margin-left: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .logo {
            display: none;
        }

        .nav-menu {
            display: block;
        }
    }

}
```

Css for the button functionality:

```css
body.is-menu-visible {
    #wrapper {
        @include vendor('filter', 'blur(0.5em)');
    }

    #menu {
        @include vendor('pointer-events', 'auto');
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```